# Raise value of integer column with ContentValues (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an SQL Update statement like:

> UPDATE table set column = column+1

Is it possible to do someting similiar with ContentValues?

> ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
>
> values.put("colum", ?);

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you could do this, try incrementing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do someting similiar with ContentValues?

No. You can only put literals in `ContentValues`, not expressions.

Under the hood the values in `ContentValues` get translated to [`sqlite3_bind...()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) calls and sqlite3 parameter binding only supports replacing literals with parameters.

To use an expression, just use `execSQL()` with the raw SQL you have.

Comment: Thank you, its a little bit sad, because i wantet to do something like if update()<1 then insert(), but then i have to split it into different commands